# update my map with uploaded mbtiles tilesets Mapbox API

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to update a custom map on Mapbox with my uploaded `tilesets` by the Mapbox API. The `MBtiles` were uploaded by using the `mapbox-Python-SDK` and stored as `tilesets`.
I need to get these `Tilesets` to a custom map by a script (The Files are Georeferenced pictures from a Drone, which I want to get displayed automatically on my map). Some kind of Livemapping. It works easy in the Mapbox Studio with the "Add tileset to style" - button, but I need to do it by the API.

I have no clue what's the best way to do it. Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the source at runtime with `map.addLayer`, or `map.addSource` and then `map.addLayer` as in this example https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/query-similar-features/ (although in your case it sounds like your source would be of `type: 'raster'`).

```
map.addSource("drone", {
    "type": "raster",
    "url": "mapbox://username.sourceid"
});

map.addLayer({
    "id": "drone-layer",
    "type": "raster",
    "source": "drone"
});
```